# Can one use paperclip to upload multiple files using one multi file selection input?

Tags: image, ruby-on-rails-3.1, paperclip

So I'm using paperclip in my rails 3.1 app,

I am adding images to an item using relationships so that I can have multiple images per item.

What I'd like to do is be able to click the browse button and select multiple files using just the single field. Rather then having to go one image at a time for each field.

Anybody know how to do this, or have a great option for doing this that doesn't require flash plugins?

Answer (score 6):

I'm using just one controller, no associations (mine is just for uploading multiple images to a gallery), but I've managed to do what you're asking. You will need to adapt it to work with your relationship, but it works great for me (although won't work in IE), I'm sure it breaks some rails conventions though, but it's the only way I could figure to build the functionality.

The first step is to set the upload field to accept multiple files using the HTML5 multiple tag:

```
<%= f.file_field :photo, multiple: 'multiple' %>
```

Or, if you're using simple_form like me:

```
<%= f.input :photo, input_html: { multiple: 'multiple' } %>
```

The next step is to change the create controller action to accept and process the multiple files. This is the bit I'm sure some will object to, but hey, it works!

```
def create

  params[:photo][:photo].each do |photo|

    @params = {}
    @params['photo'] = photo

    @photo = Photo.new(@params)

    if !@photo.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to new_photo_path, error: 'An error occured uploading.' }
      end
    end
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to photos_path, notice: 'Photos were successfully uploaded.' }
  end
end
```

It's simpler than it looks - for me the controller name is `photo` and so is the field name, which explains the `params[:photo][:photo]`. It basically just takes the `:photo` attribute of the request (where the controller would normally expect one file) and iterates over the files that have been uploaded creating a new `Photo` for each and setting the `photo` attribute of `@params` to be each file in turn then attempting to save this as a new `Photo` and alerting if an error occurs, otherwise once finished it will redirect to show the photos.

As I say, this works great for me and I hope it's helpful for you too :)

**Edit** If this hasn't been helpful, can you let me know why? Just ignoring the message after someone spent time helping isn't going to get other people to want to help you.

Answer (score 3):

Don't modify the controller, just add `name:` attribute to the form field like this:

```
<%= f.input_field :photo, as: :file, multiple: true, name: 'article[photo]' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it:

```
params[:photo][:photo].each do |photo|
  record = Photo.create(photo: photo)
  # if record.errors.any?
  #   flash[:notice] = record.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
  # end
end
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19081129/how-would-i-save-multiple-records-at-once-in-rails) for alternative ways to save multiple records.