# How would I save multiple records at once in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How would I save this array in one call with Rails?

```
tax_rates = [{
  :income_from => 0
  :income_to  => 18200
  :start => "01-07-2013"
  :finish => "30-06-2014"
  :rate => nil
  :premium => nil
  },{
  :income_from => 18201
  :income_to  => 37000
  :start => "01-07-2013"
  :finish => "30-06-2014"
  :rate => 0.19
  :premium => nil
  },{
    :income_from => 18201
    :income_to  => 37000
    :start => "01-07-2013"
    :finish => "30-06-2014"
    :rate => 0.19
    :premium => nil
    }]
```

Can I just call `Rails.create(tax_rates)`?

Also, is there a way to remove duplicate symbols so they look neater?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A nice solution is to use the [active record import gem](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import). I recommend it over now built-in Rails bulk insert because it's more flexible in the options in case of constraint violation.

```
TaxRate.import(
  [:income_from, :income_to, :start, :finish, :rate, :premium],
  tax_rates
)
```

Its definitely better than my old answer which would trigger a db commit per entry in the array :)

---

Old answer:

```
tax_rates.map {|tax_rate| TaxRate.new(tax_rate).save }
```

This way you'll retrieve an Array with `true` or `false` to know which did succeed and which didn't.

Comment: This is helpful but what if I have indexes too Like: {"0":{
  :income_from => 0.....},"1":{ :income_from => 18201...},"2":{}...}

Comment: I got the solution just use 'index' --> |index, tax_rate|.

Comment: only i needed to remove .save at the end because somehow it saves double values in table.

Comment: Terrible. This will produce a new query for each insert.

Comment: @DamienRoche Are you referring to the "Old answer" or the one that utilizes Active Record Import Gem?

Comment: @JoshuaPinter I don't recall but I assume the old answer as the new one with import would produce a bulk insert from what I understand.

Comment: @DamienRoche Thanks for the follow-up. We were assessing the use of the Active Record Import gem so needed to know if it was a single `INSERT` or not. We started using it this morning and, indeed, it does use a single `INSERT`. Thanks again.

Answer (score 29):

Your example is almost correct.

Use [`ActiveRecord::Persistence#create`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods.html#method-i-create), which can accept an array of hashes as a parameter.

```
tax_rates = [
  {
    income_from: 0,
    income_to: 18200,
    start: "01-07-2013",
    finish: "30-06-2014",
    rate: nil,
    premium: nil,
  },
  {
    income_from: 18201,
    income_to: 37000,
    start: "01-07-2013",
    finish: "30-06-2014",
    rate: 0.19,
    premium: nil,
  },
  # ...
]

TaxRate.create(tax_rates)  # Or `create!` to raise if validations fail
```

Comment: This is not working for me. I can save the hash but the validations are ignored with "!" or without. How did you do it?

Answer (score 7):

If you want all of them to be saved .or, non of them to be saved even if one fails, you can use 'ActiveRecord::Base.transaction'

e.g.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do  
   tax_rate.each do |tax_rt|  
       TaxRate.new(tax_rt).save  
    end
 end
```

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure about rails < 4.2 but I have tried it in rails 4.2 you can simply do this

```
TaxRate.create(tax_rt)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example like yours:

```
a = []

a << B.new(:name => "c")
a << B.new(:name => "s")
a << B.new(:name => "e")
a << B.new(:name => "t")
```

The array is saved all at once with:

```
a.each(&:save)
```

This will call `B#save` on each item in the array.

Comment: This solution generates multiple `INSERT` calls. It's not what OP asked for

Answer (score -2):

use a gem 'fast_inserter': https://github.com/joinhandshake/fast_inserter

it generates a single sql query of thousand records.

```
movie_data = [1, 'Climates (Iklimler)', 'Clay Pauwel', 'Drama'],
          [2, 'Tinpis Run', 'Andros Glazer', 'Comedy'],
          [3, 'Naked City, The', 'Bethena Chatband', 'Mystery'],
          [4, 'Small Time Crooks', 'Naomi Plom', 'Crime'],
          [5, 'Shadowboxer', 'Georgeanne Widdicombe', 'Thriller']

    params = {
      table: 'movies',
        static_columns: {
          created_at: '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
          updated_at: '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
        },
      options: {
        timestamps: false,
        unique: true,
        check_for_existing: true
      },
        group_size: 100,
        variable_columns: %w(id title director description),
        values: movie_data
    }
    inserter = FastInserter::Base.new(params)
    inserter.fast_insert
```